# Typesafe Activator specify parameter when running a class

Tags: scala, akka, typesafe-activator

How do we specify parameters when running a main class from Activator UI?

Surely there's a way to do that, right?

I'm using the latest one to date, 1.2.10

Thanks in advance,
Raka

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will run what you have specified as main class in build.sbt

```
  mainClass in Compile := Some("config.ConfigTest11")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. but what about the parameters to that main class?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know you can't specify parameters with activator, however you can use sbt for that:

```
sbt "run param1 param2"
```

or if you also want to specify the class name:

```
sbt "runMain my.class.Name param1 param2"
```

**Edit:**
Actually the same thing can be executed from activator:

```
activator "run param1 param2"
```

or

```
activator "runMain my.class.Name param1 param2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Start `activator`.

Type:

```
runMain com.example.TestClass parameter1 parameter2 parameter3 ... etc, etc
```

Where com.example.TestClass is the fully qualified path to your class. And parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, etc are the parameters you wish to pass to it, as many as are required.

You can also run it directly from the command line by typing:

```
activator "runMain com.example.TestClass parameter1 parameter2 parameter3 ... etc, etc"
```